# Start ScrollView Somewhere Else Besides First Image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

Hi I am looking to see if I can take my scroll view which I have created below and start the scroll view on the 3rd or 4th image rather than start the scroll view from the beginning.  Basically I dont want it to start on the first image but still be able to scroll backwards to get to them.  Is this possible? Thank you!

```
int PageCount = 34;
        NSMutableArray *arrImageName =[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"4miley.png",@"4BP1-2.png",@"S2-4.png",@"D3-4.png",@"4BP1-1.png",@"F2-4.png",@"B6-4.png",@"D6-4.png",@"4BP1-3.png",@"S1-4.png",@"B7-4.png", @"D2-4.png",@"F7-4.png",@"B1-4.png",@"F3-4.png",@"4BP1-4.png",@"D5-4.png",@"S3-4.png",@"B2-4.png",@"F5-4.png",@"D4-4.png",@"S7-4.png",@"F1-4.png",@"B3-4.png",@"S4-4.png",@"F6-4.png",@"D1-4.png",@"4BP1-5.png",@"B4-4.png",@"S5-4.png",@"F4-4.png",@"D7-4.png",@"S6-4.png",@"B5-4.png",nil];

        scroller = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
        scroller.scrollEnabled=YES;
        scroller.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [scroller setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
        scroller.pagingEnabled = YES;
        scroller.bounces = NO;
        scroller.delegate = self;
        [self.view addSubview:scroller];
        width=scroller.frame.size.width;
        xPos=0;
        for (int i=0; i<PageCount; i++)
        {
            ImgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xPos, 0, scroller.frame.size.width, scroller.frame.size.height)];
            [ImgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[arrImageName objectAtIndex:i]]];
            [scroller addSubview:ImgView];
            scroller.contentSize = CGSizeMake(width, 0);
            width +=scroller.frame.size.width;
            xPos  +=scroller.frame.size.width;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

After initializing images in scrollview , You can use `scrollRectToVisible` method to display 3rd and 4th image, set the frame of 3rd image in this method.

```
[scroller scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
//frame = your 3rd image
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you have calculated the x pos & y pos of your 3rd or 4th image, you can use

```
[scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(x, y) animated:YES];
```

or

```
 [scrollView scrollRectToVisible:rect animated:YES];//put the rect of your image
```

Answer (score 0):

After initializing images in scrollview , You can use setContentOffset:animated: method to display 3rd or 4th image

```
[scroller setContentOffset:CGPointMake(3*320, 0) animated:YES];
```